# read data from file with StreamReader into array of line 1

Tags: c#

```
 StreamReader text = new StreamReader(@textBox1.Text.ToString());
        String tempArray = text.ReadToEnd();
        char[] charA = tempArray.ToCharArray();
        Console.Write(charA);
```

output is like that

```
****4****
**26*71**
871***694
*6*****4*
2*59*67*8
*8*****2*
658***471
**94*85**
****7****
```

but ı want to write and save 1d array on 1 row simple ;

****4****
**26*71**
871***694
*6*****4*
2*59*67*8
*8*****2*
658***471
**94*85**
****7****

how can ı split this ?

Comment: my results and my array values must be ***4**** 26*71 871***694 *6*****4* 2*59*67*8 *8*****2* 658***471 94*85 ****7**** this form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on in the code you've shared:

```
StreamReader text = new StreamReader(@textBox1.Text.ToString());
String tempArray = text.ReadToEnd();
char[] charA = tempArray.ToCharArray();
Console.Write(charA);
```

`textBox1.Text` already *is* a `string`, so you don't need the `.ToString()` behind that.

By the way you don't need to prefix a field with a `@` unless it's the field has the same name as a keyword. You're free to do it anyway if you like, though).

```
StreamReader text = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
String tempArray = text.ReadToEnd();
char[] charA = tempArray.ToCharArray();
Console.Write(charA);
```

Next, if all you want to do with the file is read all its contents as a `string`, you might want to use `File.ReadAllText()` as it doesn't keep the file open:

```
String tempArray = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
char[] charA = tempArray.ToCharArray();
Console.Write(charA);
```

The console outputs multiple lines but the `char[]` still really is a 1D array. The problem is that there are newline characters in the file, which get processed by the console.

If you want to remove these newlines, it's easier to do so while you're still working with a `string` - because there are quite a few built-in features for this. Someone already commented using `string.Replace("\r\n", "")` to do this trick:

```
String tempArray = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
tempArray = tempArray.Replace("\r", "");
tempArray = tempArray.Replace("\n", "");
char[] charA = tempArray.ToCharArray();
Console.Write(charA);
```

Comment: It works!! I'm very grateful for your answer.Thank you